# What word do other countries use in place of "hoon"?

Tags: formality, dialectal-equivalent

In Australia (and seemingly New Zealand), "hoon" is actually used quite liberally (despite being informal), from media to law and parliament. Essentially it describes a person who partakes in the act of "hooning" - driving at high speeds or doing donuts, etc.

> **hoon** *Australian/NZ informal*
>
> *noun*
>   1.  a lout or hooligan, especially a young man who drives recklessly.
>   *"The whole family was wiped out because some drunken hoon had to drive
>   his car"*
>
> *verb*
>   1.  behave in a loutish way, especially by driving recklessly.
>   *"She noticed people hooning around Ohariu Valley"*

*Source: Google/Oxford*

What - if any - word is used in place of "hoon" in the UK, USA, Canada or anywhere else?

Comment: MacMillan Dictionary  suggests the following  synonyms. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/men-who-behave-badly

Comment: If the noun is specifically about drivers rather than perpetrators of other loutish behaviour, i think BE would be 'boy racer'. For the verb form, I think we've just adopted 'hooning', its certainly the word i'd expect to hear in that context in Scotland.

Comment: Driving wildly is sometimes referred to "hot dogging" in the US.

Comment: For perspective, as a long-time native AmE speaker, 1) I've never heard/seen this word before and 2) I don't think there is a corresponding word for exactly this thing and 3) The concept is obvious: 'reckless driving' is what you call it but it doesn't have the punch as the special word 'hoon'

Comment: As a long-time native BrE speaker, I've never come across the word either.

Comment: @KateBunting perhaps it is a word you only come across if you live somewhere it happens. In these parts there are a set of young folk in souped up hatchbacks who very definitely 'hoon'. In my experience it is more applied to, as it were, recreational reckless driving. They drive recklessly as a hobby rather than it just being 'how they drive'. I think its like american 'cruising' but angstier.

Comment: Am.Eng. has several terms for such a person, none of which would be acceptable use "from media to law and parliament."

Comment: @cobaltduck What would some be?

Comment: @DogLover - I was alluding to the idea that most Americans (alas, myself included) when encountering such a driver on the road, would simply draw from a long list of expletive epitaphs to describe him.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, often with regional variants, but one that has been in common British use for some time is the word [*Yobbo*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=yobbo&t=crmtb01).

Derived from [*yob*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+yob) which is backslang for boy, it describes any unsociable, often aggressive, young male.

You do nowadays also hear the variant *yoblet* - small yob - emphasizing the age of the individual.

Comment: For me, "yobbo" does not have the same driving implication as "hoon". But if someone said "driving like a yobbo", I would know exactly what they meant.

Comment: I think "yobbo" is a good word, but I agree with Christy that it doesn't have the precise connotation that "hoon" has.

Comment: As above - so I think you have to say something like *boy-racer yob*.

Answer (score 0):

For fast driving in particular, there's the term **speed demon**:

> someone who likes to drive very fast
>   <sub>[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/speed-demon)</sub>

There's also the term **joyride**, which can describe reckless driving (use 2):

> 1. a ride taken for pleasure (as in a car or aircraft); *especially* :  an automobile ride marked by reckless driving (as in a stolen car)
> 2. conduct or action resembling a joyride especially in disregard of cost or consequences
>      <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/joyride)</sub>

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Joy%20ride) also covers this meaning in listings #3 and 4.

Comment: In U.K./Ireland *joyriders* normally reserved for describing car-thieves who drive recklessly for thrills in stolen cars, rather that those doing so with their own vehicles.